# how do i assign my files as variables in sequential order?

Tags: bash

I have 10 subfolders under one folder and I have 10 .gz files under each one. I need to enter subfiles from the main file and take this .gz file and process it in a code order (from 91 to 99). I printed them all in order in the log3 file. How can I read them in the code again in order?

I was able to generate log 1,2,3 files sequentially with the following codes.

```
find . -name '*.gz' -printf '%f\0' |
sort -z |
while IFS='' read -r -d '' fname
do
    printf '%s\n' "${fname:0:4}" >&3
    printf '%s\n' "${fname:16:17}" >&4
    printf '%s\n' "${fname:0:100}" >&5
done \
   3> >(tee -a receiver_ids > log) \
   4> >(tee -a doy > log2) \
   5> >(tee -a data_record > log3)
```

but I cannot run rnxEditGde.py using these log files. I tried the code below but it can't find the -dataFile.

```
for j in {091..099}; do

ionex=$(pl $j log)
summary=$(pl $j log2)
dataRecordFile=$(pl $j log3)

gd2e.py -mkTreeS Trees
sed -i "s/jplg.*/$ionex/g" $dir/Trees/ppp_0.tree

rnxEditGde.py -dataFile "$dataRecordFile" -o dataRecordFile.Orig.gz
```

Comment: 0


my goal is to be able to run the rnxEditGde.py code. I need to enter sub-files one by one from the main file directory and read the .gz files in the rnxEditGde.py code. for example my main file is file A. Below file A there are files numbered 91 to 99. Under each of them, there are files with the .gz extension from which I need to extract information.  Files with the .gz extension are as follows,  ISTA00TUR_R_20190910000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz ISTA00TUR_R_20190920000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz ISTA00TUR_R_20190930000_01D_30S_MO.crx.gz

Comment: What is that `pl` program?

Comment: sorry i missed that part.  dir=`pwd`
function pl {                
  sed -n "$1p" $2
}

Comment: Well, what's the value of $dataRecoedFile? Does that file exist?

Comment: Please [edit] your question into a [mre] rather than hide information down here in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The form of your pl function

> function pl { sed -n "$1p" $2 }

**will look for line number $1** in the file, then print that, regardless of a match on the value of $1.  You probably wanted to use the "**//**" delimiters to define the **pattern to match** before printing the line, in this manner:

```
sed -n "/${1}/p" ${2}
```

Also, not having the braces makes the referencing of $1p ambiguous, so you really should use those, especially when you did intend to use "$1p" (without //).